# ArcSight's CEF Syslog configuration difference RAW TCP and UDP

Tags: flume, flume-ng, arcsight

What the difference in ArcSight's CEF Syslog configuration between RAW TCP and UDP  ?

is it possible that Udp syslog is sending without endline eg `\n`

How it possibole to send the syslog from ArcSight that Flumes `syslogtcp` will read it as syslog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The difference

The **RAW syslog** - Send the information over **TCP protocol**, the "RAW" is simply sends CEF payload via TCP as original data (without normalization) with `\n` ending

```
CEF:0.......
CEF:0.......
```

The **UDP syslog** - Send the information over **UDP protocol**, the "RAW" is simply sends CEF payload via TCP **without** `\n` ending - looks like stream

```
CEF:0.......CEF:0.......
```

In my tests the ArcSight version `6.9.1` **not** sending Syslog format as should

Should be:

```
Sep 10 15:19:01 host CEF:0|.............
```

Actualy:

```
CEF:0|..........
```

According https://activate.lab1.semplicityinc.com/foswiki/pub/ArcSightActivate/PLinuxOSConnectorInstallation/SyslogNGDaemonConfig.pdf and https://www.protect724.hpe.com

> When selecting Syslog Daemon, with Raw TCP, connections remain idle in a CLOSE_WAIT state until 
>   closed explicitly by the application.

More reference:
https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/4AA6-8664ENW.pdf?ver=1.0

## Apache Flume

The best practices for `ArcSight version 6.9.1` and Flume is:

1. in ArcSight use `CEF Syslog` and `RAW Tcp`
2. Flume should use NetCat source and parse it

Enjoy !